# Is the Exceptional Divisor of a Blow-up of a Variety at a point isomorphic to projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Suppose $X$ is a variety (irreducible quasi-projective algebraic set) of dimension $d$, $x\in X$, and $\pi:\tilde X\to X$ the blow-up of $X$ at $x$. Then is it true in general that the exceptional divisor of the blow-up is isomorphic to projective space of dimension $d-1$? Is it at least true for smooth projective surfaces over $\mathbb C$?

Beauville's Complex Algebraic Surfaces claims it is, but I do not understand the construction there, so I can't verify. My question is about a proof using the usual construction of the blow-up as the graph of the projection $X\dashrightarrow\mathbb P^{n-1}$ (where $X\subseteq\mathbb P^n$).

Comment: For general variety this is not true: what about the normalization of a nodal curve? For smooth varieties this is true. The point is that a point on a smooth variety is regularly embedded (see the chapter on blow up in Vakil’s FOAG).

Comment: Moreover, every variety appears as the exceptional divisor of a blow-up. Taking the cone (in the projective sense) over the variety and blowing up the vertex,